# Removing wp_login_viewport_meta

Tags: functions, wp-login-form

I'm trying to change the meta viewport tag of wp_login.php page via functions.php.

I added, successfully, the new ones via a new function and an action to login_head.

I want now to remove the existing one, but I can't seem to succeed.

I tried:

```
remove_action( 'login_head', 'wp_login_viewport_meta' );
```

But it's still showing up. Is there no way to do that?